# Page Factory @FindBy

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, pageobjects

I am currently learning page object model (POM) and I am trying to access a specific web element using @FindBy but I am not sure how to correctly write the syntax for my element into @FindBy?

What I have is:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[dta-qid='inventory']");
```

So my question is how do I place `a[da-qid='inventory']` correctly into @FindBy?

---

By, `a[da-qid='inventory']`, what I mean is that it selects every `<a>` element whose `da-qid` value begins with `'inventory'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that multiple elements will be found using this selector, try the following:

```
@FindBy(css="a[da-qid='inventory']")
List<WebElement> elements;
```

Just don't forget to choose correctly between `da-qid='inventory'` and `dta-qid='inventory'`

Answer (score 2):

Why do not you read through [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html)? Use of @FindsBy is easier if you do that with [How](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html) Enum. You have multiple options in that case. With cssSelector it should look like this

```
@FindBy(how = How.css, using = "a[dta-qid='inventory']") 
WebElement foobar;
```

Comment: there is actually no need to use the enum explicitly. you can directly declare the kind of selector in the @FindBy annotation.

Comment: @Carsten sure. That's why I said "easier". And, that's one of features commonly used and readability also matters

Comment: Okay, so it comes down to personal taste of what is easier readable ;)

Comment: @Carsten Is that a question?

Comment: No, it's not a question. I personally find the "how" parameter to be decreasing the readability, since it is cluttering the annotation body. And since we are disagreeing on that one, it is obviously a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XPath selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@da-qid,'inventory')]");
```

or

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(@da-qid,'inventory')]")
WebElement inventoryLink;
```

respectively

```
@FindAll(xpath = "//a[contains(@da-qid,'inventory')]")
List<WebElement> inventoryLinks;
```

Theoretically the XPath `"//a[startsWith(@da-qid,'inventory')]"` exists as well, but it didn't work in all WebDrivers for me.